# Can impacts from grenades score headshots in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

1. I know you can be killed by a flashbang/smoke grenade impact, and it deals 1-2 damage, but is the damage increased if the grenade hits a player's head?
2. Do HE grenades deal more damage if they explode closer to a player's head?

Comment: Please only ask one question per post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No HE Grenades don't have Critical - Headshot hit damage.

No it doesn't deal more damage when exploding near the head, it will do do maximum 57 damage to armored player and maximum 98 damage to unarmoured player.

"the player hitbox that takes the maximum damage is positioned from the waist to above the head."

[Source](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/HE_Grenade)